# checking if a tree is a heap [in prolog]

Tags: prolog

I need some help writing a predicate heap(Tree) in prolog that succeeds if Tree is a heap that satisfies both the heap property and the shape property:

- The shape property: the tree is an almost complete binary tree; that is, all levels
  of the tree, except possibly the last one (deepest) are fully filled, and, if the last
  level of the tree is not complete, the nodes of that level are filled from left to right.
- The heap property: each node is greater than or equal to each of its children
  according to some comparison predicate which is fixed for the entire data
  structure.

I would like to write 2 predicates using 2 different representations:

1. `node(K,L,R)` to represent a tree with key `K` (an integer), left subtree `L` and right subtree `R`
2. list of integers, from the root to leaf, left to right

For example:

```
?- heap1(node(5, node(4, empty, empty), empty)).
true.
```

and

```
?- heap2([5, 4, 3, 2]).
true
?- heap2([7, 6, -1, -3, 5]).
true
?- heap2([]).
true
```

I currently have very limited knowledge of Prolog and need a lot of helps defining these predicates.

Comment: sounds like you are asking us to do your homework ?

Comment: this isn't a homework... I'm actually learning Prolog on my own and trying to implement these predicates as practice, but couldn't figure it out. Some ideas would be fine

Comment: Argh! I believed you and typed up a whole answer! Your classmate is right, this is homework: www.cs.toronto.edu/~yilan/324f09/324f09a5.pdf. I see the due date is near; perhaps I'll post the answer afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

<sub>This question was deleted right after it was originally posted, because the OP was not upfront about the fact that she asked a [homework question](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~yilan/324f09/324f09a5.pdf). As the due date for the assignment has since passed, I have decided to undelete this answer.</sub>

I'm not a Prolog guru, but I gave your question some thought. I think `heap1/1` is easier to implement than `heap2/1`, because its "tree structure" is more apparent. In fact, what I will do is implement `heap1/1`, after which I'll implement `heap2/1` *in terms of* `heap1/1`.

### The tree implementation: `heap1/1`

The `empty` tree is a [binary heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap). As for `node(K, L, R)`, it is a heap if:

1. `L` and `R` are heaps.
2. If `L` and/or `R` are not `empty`, then their key is less than or equal to `K`.
3. If `L` has depth *d*, then `R` has depth *d* or *d - 1*.

So what needs to be done, is to check whether a given binary tree satisfies those properties.

- Given a `node`, we will need to traverse it to know the depth of the tree it represents. Hence we will define `heap/1` in terms of a predicate `heap/2`, in which the second argument is the tree depth. In the end we don't care about the *actual* depth, so we define:

  ```
  heap1(H) :- heap1(H, _).
  ```
- So what about `heap/2`? The base case is `empty`, which is a heap with depth `0` (or `1`, but that is irrelevant for our purposes). Thus:

  ```
  heap1(empty, 0).
  ```
- For `node(K, L, R)` we'll have to recurse. We need to test the heap properties outlined above and calculate the tree depth `H`. Thus:

  ```
  heap1(empty, 0).
  heap1(node(K, L, R), H) :-
    heap1(L, LH), heap1(R, RH),
    (L = node(LK, _, _) *-> K @>= LK; true),
    (R = node(RK, _, _) *-> K @>= RK; true),
    (LH is RH; LH is RH + 1), H is LH + 1.
  ```

  This code uses SWI-Prolog's *soft cut* [`(*->)/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=%28%2A%2D%3E%29%2f2). This mechanism is used to test whether the subtrees are non-empty, and if so, to verify that their key is smaller or equal to `K` (using [`(@>=)/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=%28%40%3E%3d%29%2f2)). The predicate [`true/0`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=true%2f0) corresponds to the situation in which one of the subtrees *is* empty. [`(is)/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=%28is%29%2f2) is used to compare the depths of the subtrees and to calculate the depth of the whole tree.

### The list implementation: `heap2/1`

I assume that `heap2/1` is supposed to check whether its sole argument is a list representing a heap stored as an array (or [*Ahnentafel list*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Ahnentafel_list)). If so, then, assuming a zero-indexed list, the children of a node at index *i* are found at indices *2i + 1* and *2i + 2*.

- As a result, a parent node is not necessarily stored right next to its child nodes. More specifically, at position *i* in the list we'll need to skip *i* or *i + 1* places to reach the keys of the subtrees. We'll define a predicate `skipn/3` to help us with that:

  ```
  skipn(N, L, E) :- (length(F, N), append(F, E, L)) *-> true; E = [].
  ```

  `skipn(N, L, E)` succeeds if `E` equals `L` after the first `N` elements of `L` have been stripped *or* if `E` is the empty list while the length of `L` is not greater than `N`. This implementation uses [`length/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=length%2f2), [`append/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=append%2f3) and again `(*->)/2` and `true/0`.
- Next up: the definition of `heap2/1`. Again we will call in the help of an auxiliary predicate, this time `heap2/3`. `heap2(H, N, T)` succeeds if the list `H`, of which the head is at position `N` of a possibly greater list, can be converted to a binary tree `T`. `heap2/1` will call `heap2/3` with initial index `0` and will verify that the resulting binary tree is in fact a heap. Thus:

  ```
  heap2(H) :- heap2(H, 0, T), heap1(T).
  ```
- Alright, we're almost there. At position `N` the index `LI` of the root of the left subtree is `2 * N + 1`. Likewise `RI = 2 * N + 2` is the index of the root of the right subtree. Since at position `N` already `N` list items have been skipped, only `LI - N` and `RI - N` elements need to be skipped to reach indices `LI` and `RI`, respectively. Thus:

  ```
  heap2([], _, empty).
  heap2([H|T], N, node(H, L, R)) :-
    LI is 2 * N + 1, RI is 2 * N + 2,
    LS is LI - N, RS is RI - N,
    skipn(LS, [H|T], LT), skipn(RS, [H|T], RT),
    heap2(LT, LI, L), heap2(RT, RI, R).
  ```